# Unstable system when low disk space

Tags: disk, system, disk-usage

When I tried to fill the system disk to full (100Mb and less space remaining), I noticed that Ubuntu is quite unstable, for example when I open the System Monitor, it doesn't open, only blink; or when I search for something in the dash, it doesn't show me all applications; etc.

I know that it is very hard for the system if it has a full system disk, but according to me Windows looks more stable when is low on system disk space. Is it possible to make Ubuntu use SWAP when it has no space on the system drive?

Comment: That's not how it works. SWAP is for low RAM only. And why did you fill your disk? Programs also require some disk space to run properly, if you have 100 MB left of course it will be unstable.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is, your system can and will not run stably with such a small amount of free disk space.  You can try a few things to try to free some space:

1.) `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

2.) `sudo apt-get install bleachbit`, then run bleachbit once normally and once as root.

Comment: I know, how to clean system, but thanks, it is just experiment :)